# Dismissing the datePicker calendar when selecting a date

Tags: swift, datepicker

I have a problem with the new datePicker update. Whenever I select a date in the calendar, in order to dismiss it, I have to tap anywhere out of the date picker to dismiss it. Is there a way to dismiss the date picker whenever I select a date?

Comment: Just answered, let me know if that fixes it. If not, I can edit it :)

Comment: @wriuhasdfhvhasdv, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it's not working. It does print `Date picker's value changed to: \(sender.date)` succesfully but it won't exit. I'm reading [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/introducing-swifts-new-modern-date-picker-37bb5e0a106) that that's just how the current date picker works: the only way to dismiss it is tapping somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of a very funny solution. It works perfectly though!

```
self.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerTapped), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
```

You select '.primaryActionTriggered' because this way your 'pickerTapped' function gets fired everytime you click on a different date in your calendar.

Then you do this:

```
@objc func pickerTapped() {
        self.datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        self.datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .automatic
    }
```

Your date picker switches from .wheels to your preferred choice so fast, the human eye doesn't see it change. All the user sees is the date picker collapsing after they selected a date.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you using done press button after selecting date. Just put this code end of your done press like:

```
func doneButtonPressed() {
 // Your code block

    self.view.endEditing(true)
 // view is your mainView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func DateSelected(_ sender: Any) {
    //Set your datePicker Value change
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.